# Codeigniter session is not working on a live server

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am trying to login my project on a live server. It is working well on localhost but on live server when I try to login it is just refreshing the page. I have been working on this problem for 3 days. I read many article but I couldn't find solution. I tried them :

In autoload.php I used :

```
['libraries'] = ('session',..)
```

My Memberlogin controller :

```
class Memberlogin extends CI_Controller 
{
   function __construct()
  {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->library('session');
   $this->load->model('Sql_model');    
  }
}
```

I tried to use

```
&CI =& get_instance(); but not working
```

In my config.php

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
```

It is not trying to reach login_check function. Just refreshing the page...

Comment: Make sure the session folder is writable chmod 777 and `$config['sess_save_path'] =  FCPATH . 'application/somefolder/';`

Comment: How can I check session folder is writable or not?

Comment: You need to use either autoload of library either load from controller. Not both.

Comment: @ofozdmr if your using file zilla to upload project you the files and folders that are uploaded you can click on right mouse button and go down to link file permissions

Comment: Tpojka, I am trying autoload and load from controller different times

Comment: wolfgang1983, I tried your suggestion but not working.